# Colors of the rainbow

Tags: meaning, science, reference-request, color

The classical Latin word for a rainbow seems to be *Iris* (*Iris* or *Iridis*, f.).
Did the Romans ever list or otherwise discuss the colors of the rainbow in extant literature?

I asked about [colors in classical Latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/275/79) earlier, and I got a nice answer.
The matter is complicated.
I just realized that rainbows look the same now as they did two millennia ago, so if the Romans named the colors of the rainbow, then we could be exactly sure about those colors and see them as they did.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since a rainbow is a gradient, there's still no way of knowing which hue a color word refers to. At best we can approximate.

Earl Anderson's [*Folk-Taxonomies in Early English*](https://books.google.com/books?id=rYT8MPFl_egC&pg=PA74#v=onepage&q&f=false) has a good discussion if it (citing [Dronke 1974](http://www.worldcat.org/title/tradition-and-innovation-in-medieval-western-color-imagery/oclc/8373647)), along with this neat chart:

[image: Table 12 - Names of rainbow colors by Greek and Roman authors]

However, there are quite a few butcherings of the Greek, so I recommend you jump straight to Edmund Veckenstedt's [*Geschichte der griechischen Farbenlehre*](https://books.google.com/books?id=3YU6AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA20#v=onepage&q&f=false). I'm actually not sure how he got what he got! Aristotle's last term was actually ἁλουργόν and not αλονρλεσ/αλουρλεσ, and it's ξανθόν and not ζανδον, κυανοῦν and not χυανουν. I don't know how well your German is, but I can help with anything you might have trouble with, that is, if you're interested in the Greek.

Edit: Links to Latin sources

- [Seneca](http://www.loebclassics.com/view/seneca_younger-natural_questions/1971/pb_LCL450.41.xml)
- [Bede](https://books.google.com/books?id=YQjHoQAZKX0C&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q=rainbow&f=false)

Comment: It is indeed true that the colors are in a continuous spectrum in a rainbow. The exact hues are not known, but it still gives some insight. I'm only interested in the Latin ones here, but Greek is a nice addition. That table is great! The only thing I miss is a more precise citation of Seneca.

Comment: Perhaps 3,12 in [*Naturales Quaestiones* 1](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/sen/sen.qn1.shtml).

Comment: I agree: the Greek is a big mess and I am disinclined to trust the Latin either. Always better to go back to the primary sources.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta That's exactly where he's getting it from. It starts from 3.11. Notice that the word for rainbow is *arcus* here. In case you don't have access to the Loeb, you can read [here online](http://www.loebclassics.com/view/seneca_younger-natural_questions/1971/pb_LCL450.41.xml) the relevant paragraph.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure what I should be looking for behind that Lucretius link; he is not in the table. Can you give more precise coordinates?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Scratch Lucretius, that was faulty memory. He mentions colors coming off colorful objects, but in book 6 when he discusses rainbows, he leaves the colors out. The two cannot be connected.

Comment: @C.M.Weimer Yeah, I was gaping in disbelief at "αλονρλεσ" for  a while before reading your comments below. How does a serious scholar make an error like that?

Comment: @brianpck Medievalists, bah! I think it might have something to do with how Classicists have a focus on language that is absent from Medievalist programs.

Comment: @C.M.Weimer "Absent" is apparently right: this isn't just bad vocabulary or syntax, which is impardonable enough, but an apparently complete lack of understanding even of the alphabet.